# 'As' always to describe something happening at the same time?

Tags: conjunctions

I heard the conjunction 'As' even when used to describe the reason for something implies it is happening at the same time. So, I'm wondering if the following sentence is a little strange to hear for the same reason.

- *As your dad studied hard back in high school, he has the right to tell you to do the same. (X / O) ?*

If I replaced 'As' with 'Because' at the begining of the sentence, would it be correct grammatically?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would still be grammatically correct. The *because* clause in the beginning of a sentence gives extra focus to the reason.

> Because breathing is something we do automatically, we rarely think
>   about it.
>   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-because-or-since